# How do I automatically cc: myself on every email sent in Lotus/IBM Notes 9.0.1?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, lotus

I'm currently on the phone with IBM and they can't seem to provide an answer. I've also searched on Google, but nothing is very clear. All I'm trying to do is automatically cc: myself on every single email I send.

I can't remember exactly where it is in Outlook nor what it is exactly called, but in Outlook I remember it was as simple as checkmarking a "automatically cc: myself" field in some preferences window.

Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to cc: yourself on every email? You have your sent folder, you can view them there.
But if you really want to send a copy to yourself you can just modify the mail application, assuming you have design access to it. You also need to turn off the nightly update of your mail application from the design template on the server.

But there is not built-in setting to do it.

**Update:** Since the reason was disclosed to be a way to use emails as a kind of to-do list, my suggestion is to use flags and follow-ups.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Karl, thanks for your response. I use my inbox as a To-Do list as well, so it holds items that need action taken on, hence cc'ing myself as a reminder to follow up on the topic discussed within. I don't believe I have design access, so I guess it sounds like I won't be able to do this, unless there's some sort of work around out there. Really appreciate the input, thank you.

Comment: Karl, IBM support finally got back to me and supported essentially exactly what you have stated. Their response: "The only thing I can think of regarding your request requires some application development.
May I know if you have developer on your side that can do the coding/development if needed? As coding for customer is out of scope for Lotus support." It's crazy that this can't be done like in Outlook, but I guess that's just how it is. Thank you Karl for your input.

Comment: It can be done in Outlook using the Rules feature because Outlook allows you to create rules for outbound mail. Notes doesn't support client-side rules for outbound messages, and I think that's unfortunate because there are other things that I think that outbound rules would be usefiul for, but I really don't think it qualifies as "crazy" that Notes won't let users do an auto-cc this way. It increases mail storage consumption! It is also just not a common request - but if it were any organization can provide it for users via a template modification or via server-side rules.

Comment: Even simpler than that in Outlook is there is just a checkbox that allows the automatic cc'ing of all outbound emails to yourself. Apparently Outlook recognizes the usefulness of it for particular cases, though as you said, it is definitely a lesser-than-average request.

Comment: @Chase: What don't you use the follow-up flag feature then? When you send a mail you set/schedule a follow-up date, you can even set an alarm to remind you about it. Then you have it in your follow-up section...

Comment: I'll have to take a look into that. Thank you much, Karl